# Google maps - get country, region and city name from longitude and latitude (PHP)

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I would like to get country, region and city name from longitude and latitude over Google maps API (V3?) - with PHP. I just can't manage to get it for every county, I managed to get this code but it doesn't work on other counties because the returned result is different (the only correct information is country but even that is returned in local name not English name):

```
<?
    $lok1 = $_REQUEST['lok1'];
    $lok2 = $_REQUEST['lok2'];

    $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.$lok2.','.$lok1.'&output=json';
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $jsondata = json_decode($data,true);

    if(is_array($jsondata )&& $jsondata ['Status']['code']==200)
    {
          $addr = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['AddressDetails']['Country']['CountryName'];
          $addr2 = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['AddressDetails']['Country']['Locality']['LocalityName'];
          $addr3 = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['AddressDetails']['Country']['Locality']['DependentLocality']['DependentLocalityName'];
    }
    echo "Country: " . $addr . " | Region: " . $addr2 . " | City: " . $addr3;
?>
```

This works great to get correct data from my country, but not for others...

Comment: Which coordinates are not working for you?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. However My application using it only in India.

Comment: you should provide more about coordinates which you have tried.

Comment: I have tried it gives address like this:Burgenlandstraße 14-16, 4020 Linz, Austria

Comment: I don't get that data, not with the code which I pasted.

Comment: I am going for few minutes. Meanwhile you can try as per my another answer. I will catch you after 20 mins.

Comment: Hiii,Have you done with the problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use second api(suggested by Thomas) like this:

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.283273,14.295041&sensor=false');

        $output= json_decode($geocode);

echo $output->results[0]->formatted_address;
```

Try this..

Edit:::::

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48.283273,14.295041&sensor=false');

        $output= json_decode($geocode);

    for($j=0;$j<count($output->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
                echo '<b>'.$output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0].': </b>  '.$output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name.'<br/>';
            }
```

Comment: This works, but the data is not the one which I need. Well, I could get country and area (but area also contains post number) from here, but can't get the city - only address. How can I get country, city/village name and area (without zip number).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my approach to the problem

```
$lat = "22.719569";
$lng = "75.857726";
$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);
$add_array  = $data->results;
$add_array = $add_array[0];
$add_array = $add_array->address_components;
$country = "Not found";
$state = "Not found"; 
$city = "Not found";
foreach ($add_array as $key) {
  if($key->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2')
  {
    $city = $key->long_name;
  }
  if($key->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1')
  {
    $state = $key->long_name;
  }
  if($key->types[0] == 'country')
  {
    $country = $key->long_name;
  }
}
echo "Country : ".$country." ,State : ".$state." ,City : ".$city;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$deal_lat=30.469301;
$deal_long=70.969324;
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$deal_lat.','.$deal_long.'&sensor=false');

        $output= json_decode($geocode);

    for($j=0;$j<count($output->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
               $cn=array($output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0]);
           if(in_array("country", $cn))
           {
            $country= $output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name;
           }
            }
            echo $country;
?>
```

Comment: It is simple code if you need to find city name then replace in_array("country", $cn) to in_array("locality", $cn) if you need to find Zip code then replacein_array("country", $cn) to in_array("postal_code", $cn)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using their GeoCoding API?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Example: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

Edit: I have used it in many apps targeting India and it has worked pretty well.

Comment: Can you help me get country, city and region from that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

its really stupid to always depend on google.

put the cities  into text file with GPS x and Y coorindates and pull from there.  all of this is available online

Answer (score 0):

if you use laravel then it will usefull for you

```
    $latitude=26.12312;
    $longitude=83.77823;
    $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;
    $response = \Http::get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', [
        'latlng' => $geolocation,
        'key' => 'api key',
        'sensor'    =>  false
    ]);
    $json_decode = json_decode($response);
    if(isset($json_decode->results[0])) {
        $response = array();
        foreach($json_decode->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponet) {
            $response[] = $addressComponet->long_name;
        }
        dd($response);
    }
```

please replace api key with your own