# Get values from multi-dimensional array via php (Google Places API)

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps, multidimensional-array, google-places-api

From the Google Places API I get an array with this structure:

```
Array
(

    [result] => Array
        (
            [address_components] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [long_name] => 1
                            [short_name] => 1
                            [types] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => street_number
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [long_name] => Theaterplatz
                            [short_name] => Theaterpl.
                            [types] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => route
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

How can I read the value for **[long_name]** from the **street_number** ?

I'm able to get it "hardcoded" with this code, but I need it "dynamically", because the key of the "address_components" ([0],[1],[2], etc.) changes depending on the query result.

```
$details = google_places_text_search($query);
echo $details[result][address_components][0][long_name];
```

Comment: You are looking for `foreach` loop.

Comment: You mean you need to filter for the record inside `[address_components]` where `[types][0] == 'street_number'` and return that record's `long_name`?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over address components and access any array key you need. Something like this.

```
$details = google_places_text_search($query);
foreach ($details['result']['address_components'] as $addressComponent) {
    echo $addressComponent['long_name'];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! :-)
Unfortunately I get no value when I try to read out the "types[0]-key like this:

echo $addressComponent['types[0]'];

I also tried it with the code provided here - no success :-/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991224/google-maps-get-country-region-and-city-name-from-longitude-and-latitude-php

Comment: Please try echo $addressComponent['types'][0];

Comment: Amamzing! This was the missing link! Thanks for your help, guys!